# Google maps v3 not a LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: not an Object name: "InvalidValueError"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Not the best with javascript and got some trouble with some google maps code but it is sporadic on MS Edge but consistent on Chrome and the markers will not load. On edge if you keep request the page sometimes it works but more than often fails.

> ERROR: not a LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: not an Object name:
>   "InvalidValueError"

script is called using below code

````
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;libraries=places"></script>```

<script async type="text/javascript" src="{{media url='scripts/store-locator.js'}}"></script>```

  require(["jquery"], function ($) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initialize();
        });

        var geocoder,
            map,
            markers = [],
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
            marker, i;

        var locations = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Store1', lat: 58.482514, lng: -1.784622 },
            { id: 2, name: 'Store2', lat: 54.687925, lng: 0.312584 }
        ];

        function initialize() {

            // set the default google map settings
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ draggable: true });
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.727440, -1.543299);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            // register the google map elements
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            // register the directions display
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));
            addMarkers();
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
                // setup control position
                control = document.getElementById('store-selector');
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);
                control.style.display = 'block';
            });
        }

        // add the markers from the array to the map
        function addMarkers() {
            $.each(locations, function (key, value) {
                // create the marker
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng),
                    map: map,
                    name: this.name

                });

                // add the marker to the cached array
                markers.push(marker);
                bounds.extend(marker.position);

                // add the event listerner for the marker click function
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        // info window display
                        map.setZoom(16);
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());


                    }
                })(marker, i));

            });
        }
    });```
````

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem.  How are you including the API? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The [posted code](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z54631bu/2/) seems to work OK for me (at least in Chrome, I don't have access to Edge ATM, I also don't have `store-locator.js`).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: what line trigger the error exactly?

Comment: store-locator.js code is shown above..just called in a separate file

Answer (score -2):

Ok I think I have resolved it thanks to geocodezip who suggested a timing issue. was erroring on  $(document).ready(function () {
            initialize();
        });

I've moved this to the bottom of the file and it seems to be running all good now..

Comment: Or... Load it as they suggest in the (very first page of the) [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)...